# Sigma Summation - Several Lower Indices

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, index-notation

I was taking a look to a book of statistical mechanics, many equations show something as follows:
$$ Q(K,N) = \Sigma_{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}=\pm 1}[ e^{K(...+s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_3s_4...)} ]$$
then they partition the sum as follows
$$ Q(K,N) = \Sigma_{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}}e^{K(s_1s_2+s_2s_3)}e^{K(s_3s_4+s_4s_5)} ... $$
After Summing over even numbered S's
$$Q(K,N) = \Sigma_{s_{odd}} (e^{K(s_1+s_3)}+e^{-K(s_1+s_2)})(e^{K(s_3+s_5)}+e^{-K(s_3+s_5)})$$
How can I interpret this Summation with many lower indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q(K,N) 
= \Sigma_{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}=\pm 1}[ e^{K(...+s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_3s_4...)} ]
$

To me,
it looks like
the summation is over
the $2^N$ sets
$\{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{N}\}
$
where each $s_i$
is either $1$
or $-1$.

For example,
for $N=2$,
these are

$\{1, 1\},
\{1, -1\},
\{-1, 1\},
\{-1, -1\}
$.

Comment: So would we sum in the following way:  $$\Sigma_{S_1} F(S_i)=F(1) + F(-1)$$ and $$\Sigma_{S_1,S_2,...} F(S_i)=(F(1) + F(-1))+(F(1) + F(-1))+...$$